# prevent access to specific directory in my home directory for other user?

Tags: linux, bash, access-rights

I have one directory that I would like to prevent access for specific user. For example `/home/myuser/secret` should not be readable, accessible etc to specific user. He can see that directoty exists, but can't access / read its contents or modify any way.

How can I do that?

Comment: Other user should "navigate" into that home dir and only "a specific" (or a subset) user could not?

Comment: Other users if not specified, can see that directory on default. But if I specify to specific user that he can't see what's inside that dir, he should not see it

Comment: Andrius: no, other users can't by default into a unix system. However, I'll answer you under here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filesystem supports ACLs, you can do this:

```
setfacl -m "u:dude:---" /home/myuser/secret
```

Which says the user `dude` should have no access (neither `r` nor `w` nor `x`) to that directory.

To verify, run the `getfacl` command:

```
$ getfacl /home/myuser/secret
# file: home/myuser/secret
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
user::rwx
user:dude:---
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Linux Permissions are set as "Whitelist". You try to specify a blacklist.

I'w create a group with all user who should have access.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let other user navigate an *arbitrary* /home/ dir of another user, but you want to deny others to do that, you can procede as follows

- let group to read and execute on that folder `chmod 750 /home/myuser/secret`
- create a group that will be assigned to that folder `groupadd secret_users`
- `chown -R :secret_users /home/myuser/secret`
- add users to the group by editing `/etc/group` file. user inserted here could read files inside that folder but other users can't